# Effeciency, hidden HTML or JavaScript DOM appending?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cordova

I am working on a simple Cordova app with about 4 page types and I am trying to think through which is the better way to handle the inner HTML templates.

1. Hidden HTML hard coded into the HTML files that is hidden and populated/revealed by my JS.
2. Using a JS template system and appending and removing from the DOM.

I feel that appending all that to the DOM for a page is inefficient when I could just update the sections that change. But perhaps an append is lightweight enough where I shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I suppose, perhaps doing all the population and then appending once is much lighter weight then updating multiple fields separately that already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do it. In terms of load on the browser. That is hard to say. From your question it is hard to know what is in these pages, what are you displaying, is it live data, static html etc.

When you first plot out an app, if you are from the old class of building multiple page websites, it can be a little concerning as to how well your app/page will run with all those pages crammed in to one, and all that data plus code.

The answer is, amazingly well. If done properly in modern browsers, and for example Ipads the app will run to near native performance.

The options you have are

1. Map all the pages into one HTML document. Hide each page content using css display:none, flip them into view using css animation, fading or just display:block.
2. Use a javascript routing library to map urls to blocks of code that deal with each page, this makes mapping out your app much easier, and means that buttons can just link to your pages, like a real website. see http://projects.jga.me/routie/
3. Building all the page templates into one page can make it hard to code, as the page becomes enormous, consider breaking the inner content of each page into separate files, you can then give each page holder a url and use a small xhr request to load the page on-the fly, once loaded you can cache it into memory or even local-storage, depending on whether you remove it when it is closed or keep it hidden.

In my experience you can put an enormous number or nodes into one page and have very little speed drop, bear in mind if you use something like jquery and do a lot of $(".page > .page1 > .items li") your going to have a slow app.

**Tips**

1. Use element ID's everywhere document.getElementById(..) is 100's of times faster in a loop that $(...)
2. cache elements when you find them, if you need them later store them in a memory cache.
3. keep for loop inner code to a minimum.
4. use a decent click touch libary like http://hammerjs.github.io/ and delegate all the events of the body tag or at least on each page.
5. If you need to touch the server, load data, think dom first, device second server later. A good app is a responsive app, that responds to the user instantly.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been posted a while ago, but for the sake of the users I am going to add my answer.

I completely agree with MartinWebb but my answer will shed some light on the results of his options. I am currently working on a similar project. Please note that this answer pertains to cordova (previously called phonegap) specifically. My app has about 5 pages with +-20 different components (input's, div's, h1's, p's, etc.). This is what i tried and the result of each:

1. jQuery was my first option, mainly because it is easy to use and reduces the amount of code required to accomplish a said goal. **Result:** First time I tried this approach I though I would spice it up with animations and transformations. The result of this was a *very* unresponsive app. I removed the animation and transformation, however due to the nature of my application I required multiple dynamically added components and jQuery just wasn't up for the task.
2. Css `display:none` and `visible:hidden` was my next option. I used javascript's dom to display certain div's. **Result:** This works if your not planning on switching many div shortly after one another eg. a simple menu. It quickly became apparent that this wasn't going to work. Also this does not eliminate my need for the dom. Remember `document.getElementById('menu').style.display = "none";` is still part of the dom. This as a solution, for me, is poor. There is a reason that `var menu= document.createElement('div');` is part of the language. Which brings me to my last option.
3. Building a page 90% on javascript's dom was my last option. Logically I could not see how 600 lines of code cold trump one `.innerHTML` or `.style.display = "block";` but it did. **Result:** It was by far the most responsive of all the solutions.

I'm not saying that all webpages should be coded with dom appending, but as I stated previously, for a cordova app of a few pages (<6), with a few components a javascript dom appending approach would be best. It takes longer to code, but you will be rewarded with control and efficiency. I would suggest coding the backbone of your app in html and populating and controlling with javascript's dom.

Best of luck.

Comment: Using jquery for this kind of app, will destroy performance. I use my own framework. These days their are many frameworks that achieve these results. Furthermore animations will/can affect the performance. fast fade 200ms or just flipping pages is far better.

Answer (score 0):

The first option, `<div>`s with `display:none;` would be more efficient by a small margin, but you can get the best of both worlds by compiling your JavaScript and templates together into a single file using something like browserify or require.js.

Comment: Yeah, I am using Require. More curious about the resources the browser needs to add a large chunk of HTML with JS...